# Passing data to table view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a view controller, and I have one tableview inside this view controller. I am managing the table from table view controller. But I need to send data to tableview controller from view controller. How can I do this ?

**This is my view controller:**

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
```

And this is my table view controller:

```
class SettingsTableViewController:UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet var notificationsSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBAction func notificationsClicked(sender: UISwitch) {
        if notificationsSwitch.on {
            println("notifications on")
        }else{
            println("notifications off")
        }
    }

}
```

Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: println? isn't that Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu I tried but i am getting following error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value How can I resolve ?

Comment: to answer that, we need more code: where does the error occur, when does it occur. etc

Comment: @Okan Did you follow the link I commented?

Comment: @dasdom yes but I couldn't find any info for swift

Comment: Learn to read Objective-C. The community won't answer all the question again.

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu could you look this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105446/delegation-between-view-controller-and-table-view-controller

Answer (score 1):

Use action segues in combination with a prepareForSegue function. Described in this article:

[Storyboards Tutorial in Swift: Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2)

Add an identifier for your push segue that opens the SettingsTableViewController and add the following function to ViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToTableView" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! SettingsTableViewController
        destinationController.notificationsSwitch.setOn(true, animated:true)
    }
}
```

Assuming that you want to pass some bool from the settingsViewController to the table, you will have something like:

```
var notifications: Bool = false
```

In the Interface builder, add an identifier to the push segue like this:
[image: Push segue identifier in IB]

*edit: slightly misunderstood the problem initially, since the data is not passed from SettingsTableViewController to settingsViewController but the other way around. Using segues and prepareForSegue is generally the way to pass on data to another viewController.*

*edit2: changed the way to set the switch in the prepareForSegue function.*

Comment: I am not using segues for this operation. I couldn't understand you answer.

Comment: segues are the way to go to pass on data between view controllers. I have edited my answer for your question.

Comment: I get it you now. But I have one more problem. I am getting data from server so I need to wait data then when it comes I need to use in segue. How can I do this ?

Comment: @RuudKalis, "are the way to go." Only IF you are using segues. (which I think the OP is using).

Comment: Agree @Firo.. looking at the Okan's screenshot of the IB builder there is a push segue used to open the SettingsTableViewController.

Comment: @Okan: the problem with data arriving from the server is a different question. Please search on StackOverflow and if you do not find an answer, post a new question.

Comment: Can I use notification center for this case ?

Comment: Notifications are used inside the app to send notifications to one or several listeners (e.g. viewControllers). If you have a network server sending data I would use sockets. Check this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: You got it wrong. After I receive the data from server can I use notification center to pass to tableview controller ?

Comment: I would not use the notification center for this problem. The notification center is used to display a message, play a sound or update a badge on the app's icon. They are not designed to send data to a tableview. https://developer.apple.com/notifications/